# How to navigate through the nested JSON file using index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm pretty new to coding and currently, I'm coding a React native project. Sorry, if the question is too simple. I have tried many ways to navigate but failed. 
I have a JSON file and the data are as below.

```
{
"values" : {
      "EquityTechnology": {
        "_figure": [
          9.138790534659202
        ],
        "ICICIPrudentialTechnologyFundGrowth": {
          "_figure": [
            10.6484932862722
          ]
        },
        "Franklin Infotech Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            7.96902834459266
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life New Millenium Fund - Growth - Regular Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            8.79884997311275
          ]
        },
        "SBI IT FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - SmallCap": {
        "_figure": [
          14.0064060591969
        ],
        "HDFC Small Cap Fund - Regular Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Mid & Small Cap Fund -Growth Plan -Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            11.8481966627509
          ]
        },
        "Franklin India Smaller Companies Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            15.3302065566009
          ]
        },
        "Sundaram S.M.I.L.E.Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            11.754220292209
          ]
        },
        "SBI Magnum MIDCAP FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.9351631127958
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Small & Midcap Fund - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            12.3666676648488
          ]
        },
        "L&T Emerging Businesses Fund - Regular Plan - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Canara Robeco Emerging Equities - Regular Plan - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.6579568171628
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Small Cap Fund - Growth Plan - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            15.0019513606657
          ]
        },
        "DSP BlackRock Micro Cap Fund - Regular - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            16.1568860065413
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - Pharma": {
        "_figure": [
          12.966782129169834
        ],
        "SBI PHARMA - REGULAR PLAN -GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.9918670876748
          ]
        },
        "UTI Pharma & Healthcare Fund-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            11.2119667676491
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Pharma Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            12.6965125321856
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - MultiCap": {
        "DSP BlackRock Equity Fund - Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            8.32832307169916
          ]
        },
        "DSP BlackRock Opportunities Fund-Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            9.72369143832476
          ]
        },
        "MOSt Focused Multicap 35-Regular Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Equity Opportunities  Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            9.79339882843478
          ]
        },
        "L&T Equity Fund-Regular Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "IIFL India Growth Fund -Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "SBI Magnum Multicap Fund - REGULAR PLAN -Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            10.1704693596904
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Select Focus Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            10.7785458258239
          ]
        },
        "HDFC Equity Fund - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            8.29168295966879
          ]
        },
        "Franklin India Flexi Cap Fund-Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            9.52777086776355
          ]
        },
        "_figure": [
          9.998290130663644
        ],
        "Franklin India High Growth Companies Fund - Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            12.0111958711599
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Equity Fund - Growth - Regular Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            10.5597033707683
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential Value Discovery Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            12.494420125849
          ]
        },
        "Axis Equity Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            8.30198971811754
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - FMCG": {
        "_figure": [
          12.9391809175777
        ],
        "SBI FMCG FUND - REGULAR - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential FMCG Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            12.9391809175777
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - Banking": {
        "_figure": [
          7.756301964533782
        ],
        "UTI Banking Sector Fund-Income Option": {
          "_figure": [
            4.48544488820235
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Banking ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Banking and Financial Services Fund - Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "R*Shares Bank BeES": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Banking Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            8.2686147173821
          ]
        },
        "SBI BANKING & FINANCIAL SERVICES FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential Banking and Financial Services Fund -  Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            11.0147287026105
          ]
        },
        "UTI Banking Sector Fund-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            7.25641954994018
          ]
        }
      },
      "Gold Fund": {
        "R*Shares Gold BeES": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "_figure": [
          4.0762242905284065
        ],
        "HDFC Gold Exchange Traded Fund": {
          "_figure": [
            6.03459415600124
          ]
        },
        "SBI GOLD EXCHANGE TRADED SCHEME": {
          "_figure": [
            6.14783904734468
          ]
        },
        "KOTAK GOLD ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            -3.40119263557552
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Gold Fund Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            5.61706623223513
          ]
        },
        "Axis Gold ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            5.9828146526365
          ]
        }
      }
      }
}
```

I want to navigate through the JSON using the index as the data will be dynamic and the names could change over time. What should I do to access, for example,  '14.9918670876748' under '_figure' of 'SBI PHARMA - REGULAR PLAN -GROWTH' which in turn is under 'Equity - Pharma'. I want to retrieve '_figure' of all the items. I have tried for..in loop but it returned only the indexes of nested objects. Is there any way I can navigate through the JSON file using indexes?

Thank you in advance.

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: why are you using object in the first place then use array for that purpose?

Comment: Do you want to access all figures?

Comment: hi Nadir, I want to access all the figures. The JSON data was given to me in this structure.

Comment: Is it okay if all the figures are retuned in an array?

Comment: yeah, no problem, Nadir.

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: You can't navigate raw JSON at all—you need to decode it first. Is it too big to make it inconvenient to load it into memory?

Comment: I dont get it. So you always want value of SBI PHARMA - REGULAR PLAN -GROWTH? There is only one of those in the data so why looping is needed at all?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, Henrik. I want to access all the '_figure'  in the JSON data. I have edited the OP now.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rObj = {
"values" : {
      "EquityTechnology": {
        "_figure": [
          9.138790534659202
        ],
        "ICICIPrudentialTechnologyFundGrowth": {
          "_figure": [
            10.6484932862722
          ]
        },
        "Franklin Infotech Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            7.96902834459266
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life New Millenium Fund - Growth - Regular Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            8.79884997311275
          ]
        },
        "SBI IT FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - SmallCap": {
        "_figure": [
          14.0064060591969
        ],
        "HDFC Small Cap Fund - Regular Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Mid & Small Cap Fund -Growth Plan -Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            11.8481966627509
          ]
        },
        "Franklin India Smaller Companies Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            15.3302065566009
          ]
        },
        "Sundaram S.M.I.L.E.Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            11.754220292209
          ]
        },
        "SBI Magnum MIDCAP FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.9351631127958
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Small & Midcap Fund - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            12.3666676648488
          ]
        },
        "L&T Emerging Businesses Fund - Regular Plan - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Canara Robeco Emerging Equities - Regular Plan - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.6579568171628
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Small Cap Fund - Growth Plan - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            15.0019513606657
          ]
        },
        "DSP BlackRock Micro Cap Fund - Regular - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            16.1568860065413
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - Pharma": {
        "_figure": [
          12.966782129169834
        ],
        "SBI PHARMA - REGULAR PLAN -GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.9918670876748
          ]
        },
        "UTI Pharma & Healthcare Fund-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            11.2119667676491
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Pharma Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            12.6965125321856
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - MultiCap": {
        "DSP BlackRock Equity Fund - Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            8.32832307169916
          ]
        },
        "DSP BlackRock Opportunities Fund-Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            9.72369143832476
          ]
        },
        "MOSt Focused Multicap 35-Regular Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Equity Opportunities  Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            9.79339882843478
          ]
        },
        "L&T Equity Fund-Regular Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "IIFL India Growth Fund -Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "SBI Magnum Multicap Fund - REGULAR PLAN -Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            10.1704693596904
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Select Focus Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            10.7785458258239
          ]
        },
        "HDFC Equity Fund - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            8.29168295966879
          ]
        },
        "Franklin India Flexi Cap Fund-Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            9.52777086776355
          ]
        },
        "_figure": [
          9.998290130663644
        ],
        "Franklin India High Growth Companies Fund - Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            12.0111958711599
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Equity Fund - Growth - Regular Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            10.5597033707683
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential Value Discovery Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            12.494420125849
          ]
        },
        "Axis Equity Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            8.30198971811754
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - FMCG": {
        "_figure": [
          12.9391809175777
        ],
        "SBI FMCG FUND - REGULAR - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential FMCG Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            12.9391809175777
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - Banking": {
        "_figure": [
          7.756301964533782
        ],
        "UTI Banking Sector Fund-Income Option": {
          "_figure": [
            4.48544488820235
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Banking ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Banking and Financial Services Fund - Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "R*Shares Bank BeES": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Banking Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            8.2686147173821
          ]
        },
        "SBI BANKING & FINANCIAL SERVICES FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential Banking and Financial Services Fund -  Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            11.0147287026105
          ]
        },
        "UTI Banking Sector Fund-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            7.25641954994018
          ]
        }
      },
      "Gold Fund": {
        "R*Shares Gold BeES": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "_figure": [
          4.0762242905284065
        ],
        "HDFC Gold Exchange Traded Fund": {
          "_figure": [
            6.03459415600124
          ]
        },
        "SBI GOLD EXCHANGE TRADED SCHEME": {
          "_figure": [
            6.14783904734468
          ]
        },
        "KOTAK GOLD ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            -3.40119263557552
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Gold Fund Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            5.61706623223513
          ]
        },
        "Axis Gold ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            5.9828146526365
          ]
        }
      }
      }
}

//console.log(rObj.values;);
//container
var values = rObj.values;
//Index
var find = "Equity - Pharma";
//subIndex
var subFind = "SBI PHARMA - REGULAR PLAN -GROWTH";
var case1 = values[find][subFind]["_figure"][0];
If you want to find the specific just change the variables the corresponding 
names [find] i.e "Equity - Pharma" then subFind i.e "SBI PHARMA - REGULAR 
PLAN -GROWTH"

for(var index in values) {
    if(index === find) {
        var nextIndex = values[index];
        for(var nextFind in nextIndex) {
            var Item = nextIndex[nextFind];
            if(nextFind === subFind) {
                  console.log(Item["_figure"][0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Evil Dr. PorkChop.

Comment: :) oink oink!~~

Answer (score 0):

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` should do the trick. This will get you the key as well as the value while iterating.
For example:

```
var buz = {
  fog: 'stack'
};

for (var name in buz) {
  if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    console.log('this is fog (' + 
      name + ') for sure. Value: ' + buz[name]);
  }
  else {
    console.log(name); // toString or something else
  }
}
```

Documentation link: [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to extract all the _figure from object as array.

```
var figures=[];
Object.keys(data.values).forEach(function(val){
 Object.keys(data.values[val]).forEach(function(_val){
    if(data.values[val][_val]&&data.values[val][_val]._figure){
       figures.push(data.values[val][_val]._figure[0]);
    }
  });
})

console.log(figures);
```

**SNIPPET-1**

```js
var data = {
"values" : {
      "EquityTechnology": {
        "_figure": [
          9.138790534659202
        ],
        "ICICIPrudentialTechnologyFundGrowth": {
          "_figure": [
            10.6484932862722
          ]
        },
        "Franklin Infotech Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            7.96902834459266
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life New Millenium Fund - Growth - Regular Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            8.79884997311275
          ]
        },
        "SBI IT FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - SmallCap": {
        "_figure": [
          14.0064060591969
        ],
        "HDFC Small Cap Fund - Regular Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Mid & Small Cap Fund -Growth Plan -Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            11.8481966627509
          ]
        },
        "Franklin India Smaller Companies Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            15.3302065566009
          ]
        },
        "Sundaram S.M.I.L.E.Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            11.754220292209
          ]
        },
        "SBI Magnum MIDCAP FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.9351631127958
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Small & Midcap Fund - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            12.3666676648488
          ]
        },
        "L&T Emerging Businesses Fund - Regular Plan - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Canara Robeco Emerging Equities - Regular Plan - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.6579568171628
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Small Cap Fund - Growth Plan - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            15.0019513606657
          ]
        },
        "DSP BlackRock Micro Cap Fund - Regular - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            16.1568860065413
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - Pharma": {
        "_figure": [
          12.966782129169834
        ],
        "SBI PHARMA - REGULAR PLAN -GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.9918670876748
          ]
        },
        "UTI Pharma & Healthcare Fund-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            11.2119667676491
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Pharma Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            12.6965125321856
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - MultiCap": {
        "DSP BlackRock Equity Fund - Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            8.32832307169916
          ]
        },
        "DSP BlackRock Opportunities Fund-Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            9.72369143832476
          ]
        },
        "MOSt Focused Multicap 35-Regular Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Equity Opportunities  Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            9.79339882843478
          ]
        },
        "L&T Equity Fund-Regular Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "IIFL India Growth Fund -Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "SBI Magnum Multicap Fund - REGULAR PLAN -Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            10.1704693596904
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Select Focus Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            10.7785458258239
          ]
        },
        "HDFC Equity Fund - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            8.29168295966879
          ]
        },
        "Franklin India Flexi Cap Fund-Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            9.52777086776355
          ]
        },
        "_figure": [
          9.998290130663644
        ],
        "Franklin India High Growth Companies Fund - Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            12.0111958711599
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Equity Fund - Growth - Regular Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            10.5597033707683
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential Value Discovery Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            12.494420125849
          ]
        },
        "Axis Equity Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            8.30198971811754
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - FMCG": {
        "_figure": [
          12.9391809175777
        ],
        "SBI FMCG FUND - REGULAR - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential FMCG Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            12.9391809175777
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - Banking": {
        "_figure": [
          7.756301964533782
        ],
        "UTI Banking Sector Fund-Income Option": {
          "_figure": [
            4.48544488820235
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Banking ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Banking and Financial Services Fund - Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "R*Shares Bank BeES": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Banking Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            8.2686147173821
          ]
        },
        "SBI BANKING & FINANCIAL SERVICES FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential Banking and Financial Services Fund -  Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            11.0147287026105
          ]
        },
        "UTI Banking Sector Fund-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            7.25641954994018
          ]
        }
      },
      "Gold Fund": {
        "R*Shares Gold BeES": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "_figure": [
          4.0762242905284065
        ],
        "HDFC Gold Exchange Traded Fund": {
          "_figure": [
            6.03459415600124
          ]
        },
        "SBI GOLD EXCHANGE TRADED SCHEME": {
          "_figure": [
            6.14783904734468
          ]
        },
        "KOTAK GOLD ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            -3.40119263557552
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Gold Fund Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            5.61706623223513
          ]
        },
        "Axis Gold ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            5.9828146526365
          ]
        }
      }
      }
};

var figures=[];
Object.keys(data.values).forEach(function(val){
 Object.keys(data.values[val]).forEach(function(_val){
    if(data.values[val][_val]&&data.values[val][_val]._figure){
       figures.push(data.values[val][_val]._figure[0]);
    }
  });
})

console.log(figures);
```

or you can try this.

```
JSON.stringify(data).match(/"_figure":\[[0-9.]+\]/g).map(function(val){
      return parseFloat(val.match(/[0-9.]+/g)[0])
});
```

**SNIPPET-2**

```js
var data = {
"values" : {
      "EquityTechnology": {
        "_figure": [
          9.138790534659202
        ],
        "ICICIPrudentialTechnologyFundGrowth": {
          "_figure": [
            10.6484932862722
          ]
        },
        "Franklin Infotech Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            7.96902834459266
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life New Millenium Fund - Growth - Regular Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            8.79884997311275
          ]
        },
        "SBI IT FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - SmallCap": {
        "_figure": [
          14.0064060591969
        ],
        "HDFC Small Cap Fund - Regular Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Mid & Small Cap Fund -Growth Plan -Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            11.8481966627509
          ]
        },
        "Franklin India Smaller Companies Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            15.3302065566009
          ]
        },
        "Sundaram S.M.I.L.E.Fund-Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            11.754220292209
          ]
        },
        "SBI Magnum MIDCAP FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.9351631127958
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Small & Midcap Fund - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            12.3666676648488
          ]
        },
        "L&T Emerging Businesses Fund - Regular Plan - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Canara Robeco Emerging Equities - Regular Plan - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.6579568171628
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Small Cap Fund - Growth Plan - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            15.0019513606657
          ]
        },
        "DSP BlackRock Micro Cap Fund - Regular - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            16.1568860065413
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - Pharma": {
        "_figure": [
          12.966782129169834
        ],
        "SBI PHARMA - REGULAR PLAN -GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            14.9918670876748
          ]
        },
        "UTI Pharma & Healthcare Fund-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            11.2119667676491
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Pharma Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            12.6965125321856
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - MultiCap": {
        "DSP BlackRock Equity Fund - Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            8.32832307169916
          ]
        },
        "DSP BlackRock Opportunities Fund-Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            9.72369143832476
          ]
        },
        "MOSt Focused Multicap 35-Regular Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Equity Opportunities  Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            9.79339882843478
          ]
        },
        "L&T Equity Fund-Regular Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "IIFL India Growth Fund -Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "SBI Magnum Multicap Fund - REGULAR PLAN -Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            10.1704693596904
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Select Focus Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            10.7785458258239
          ]
        },
        "HDFC Equity Fund - Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            8.29168295966879
          ]
        },
        "Franklin India Flexi Cap Fund-Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            9.52777086776355
          ]
        },
        "_figure": [
          9.998290130663644
        ],
        "Franklin India High Growth Companies Fund - Growth Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            12.0111958711599
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Equity Fund - Growth - Regular Plan": {
          "_figure": [
            10.5597033707683
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential Value Discovery Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            12.494420125849
          ]
        },
        "Axis Equity Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            8.30198971811754
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - FMCG": {
        "_figure": [
          12.9391809175777
        ],
        "SBI FMCG FUND - REGULAR - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential FMCG Fund - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            12.9391809175777
          ]
        }
      },
      "Equity - Banking": {
        "_figure": [
          7.756301964533782
        ],
        "UTI Banking Sector Fund-Income Option": {
          "_figure": [
            4.48544488820235
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Banking ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Birla Sun Life Banking and Financial Services Fund - Regular Plan - Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "R*Shares Bank BeES": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "Reliance Banking Fund-Growth Plan-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            8.2686147173821
          ]
        },
        "SBI BANKING & FINANCIAL SERVICES FUND - REGULAR PLAN - GROWTH": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "ICICI Prudential Banking and Financial Services Fund -  Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            11.0147287026105
          ]
        },
        "UTI Banking Sector Fund-Growth Option": {
          "_figure": [
            7.25641954994018
          ]
        }
      },
      "Gold Fund": {
        "R*Shares Gold BeES": {
          "_figure": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "_figure": [
          4.0762242905284065
        ],
        "HDFC Gold Exchange Traded Fund": {
          "_figure": [
            6.03459415600124
          ]
        },
        "SBI GOLD EXCHANGE TRADED SCHEME": {
          "_figure": [
            6.14783904734468
          ]
        },
        "KOTAK GOLD ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            -3.40119263557552
          ]
        },
        "Kotak Gold Fund Growth": {
          "_figure": [
            5.61706623223513
          ]
        },
        "Axis Gold ETF": {
          "_figure": [
            5.9828146526365
          ]
        }
      }
      }
};

var figures = JSON.stringify(data).match(/"_figure":\[[0-9.]+\]/g).map(function(val){
      return parseFloat(val.match(/[0-9.]+/g)[0])
});

console.log(figures);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nadir. will try this.